# Change character vector 2000Q1, 2000Q2,.. etc. to date type in R

Tags: r, date

Is it possible to change a vector of character values 2000Q1, 2000Q2,2000Q3, 2000Q4,2001Q1, ..., i.e. a vector of quarterly dates, to date values? I have already tried something like this:

```
Dat <- c(2000Q1, 2000Q2,2000Q3, 2000Q4,2001Q1)
Dat<-as.Date(Dat ,format="%Y%Q")
```

But that didn't work. Could someone help me out?

Comment: you can use `library(zoo);as.Date(as.yearqtr(Dat))` make sure there are quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can do

```
as.Date(
  sapply(strsplit(Dat, 'Q'), 
    function(x) paste(1, seq(1,10,3)[as.integer(x[2])], x[1], sep = '-')),
  format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```